# How to filter words from a list/series/data frame using the first letter as argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Example:

```
list = [word, christmas, banana, jupyter] #it can be also a series or dataframe.
```

I want to select the words which start with "W" and "C" and put these words into a new list/series/data frame.

I tried something like this and it doesn't work:

```
wc_words = []
for word in list:
    if word.str.startswith(('W','C')):
        wc_words.append(word)
```

Comment: Just write `word.startswith()`, no need the `.str` .

Answer (score 2):

You could try Python's [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function. It's built-in:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda string: string.startswith(('W','C')), original_list))
```

The `filter(function, iterable)` function will return an iterator and the list casts the iterator to your needed list.

The function needs an argument to judge, so the `lambda` expression here is just a wrapper to convert it to the needed form.

Answer (score 0):

If you have list then try with list comprehension:

```
out=[x.lower() for x in lst if x[0] in ['w','c']]
```

If you have series:

```
out=ser[ser.str[0].str.lower().isin(['w','c'])]
#You can also use str.startswith() but you have to use it 2 times with | condition
```

If you have dataframe:

```
df.loc[df['objects'].str[0].str.lower().isin(['w','c'])]
#OR
#df.loc[df['objects'].str.startswith('w') | df['objects'].str.startswith('c')]
```

Sample code:

```
ser = pd.Series(['word', 'christmas', 'banana','jupyter'])
lst = ['word', 'christmas', 'banana','jupyter']
df=pd.DataFrame(['word', 'christmas', 'banana','jupyter'],columns=['objects'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have gone for the [solution proposed by victrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68792094/16343464), so here is an alternative:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x[0].lower() in ('w', 'c'), my_list))
```

*NB. this solution is case insensitive*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a list of strings, there you go:

```
my_words=['word', 'christmas', 'banana', 'jupyter']
wc_words = list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith(('w', 'c')), my_words))
```

But I've noticed you didn't use strings on your list. If those are variable names and you want to filter the variables that start with "w" or "c", you'll need to get the variable names as strings and then filter it:

```
words = 'string'
christmas = 3
banana = False
jupyter = {'a': 'b'}

my_words = [words, christmas, banana, jupyter]
wc_values = my_words.copy()

for word in my_words:
    v = vars()
    if not list(filter(lambda x: v.get(x)==word, v))[0].startswith(('w', 'c')):
        wc_values.remove(word)
```